# Maven nested dependency is not accessible

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have a maven project and in the parent POM and I have declared some dependencies inside this parent POM. This POM is used within the child POM as shown in the code snippet. When compiling the Child project, IntelliJ complains that it cannot find an interface used within the parent project.This interface is declared within the dependency "anotherApp" in the parent POM.

My understanding about Maven dependencies is that, since I have declared the dependency in Parent POM, it should get inherited in the child POM as well and child should be able to access these dependencies and their classes / interfaces without an issue.

I tried adding the dependency inside dependencyManagement tag in parent POM. But cannot achieve what I expect to get. I also looked into the dependency trees of both parent and child projects. In parent, dependency tree shows anotherApp as its dependency, but in child, only parent is shown as a dependency, anotherApp is not shown as a dependency came through parent.

This is how my parent POM looks like

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>it.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>commonParent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../CommonParent/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
          <artifactId>anotherApp</artifactId>
          <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is how my child POM looks like

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>it.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>commonParent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../CommonParent/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>child</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.app</groupId>
          <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

There is an interface Foo declared inside "anotherApp". This interface is accessible by the parent project. But child project cannot access this interface. IntelliJ complains that it cannot access this interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things that need to be corrected:

- The parent POM should have `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.
- The child project should *not* use the parent POM as dependency, but add it in the `<parent>` tag.

Comment: I cannot do that because I need the parent to bind into a jar and the child already have another parent. Can you please tell me if there is a way to get the dependencies added in parent pom to child project. IntelliJ suggest adding the "anotherApp" dependency to child, but I want it to come through the parent as I have already added parent as a dependency to child

Comment: I have edited by code snippet so you can get a better understanding about this issue

Comment: Calling it "parent" and "child" is misleading because your "parent" really is a dependency of "child". Due to transitive dependency resolution, Maven will also find the dependency "anotherApp". Usually, you can access its content as well, but there are several reasons this might not be the case (E.g. you set the scope to runtime, test or provided in dependencyManagement or IntelliJ is not up to date with the project). Please consider: If you use a class/interface directly in your source code, you should add the relevant jar as direct dependency (not rely on it transitively).